# Does anyone have electricity consumption data of Turkey on hourly basis for last 25 years or any period?

Tags: data-request, energy

I am looking for electricity consumption data for provinces/ districts/regions of Turkey for last 25 years (or any period) on an hourly basis. On there official statistics site it is available only on yearly basis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no an open data for that. [The official statistics site](https://data.tuik.gov.tr) and [TEİAŞ](https://www.teias.gov.tr) have main statistical data for electricity consumption. If both don't have it, you won't find it anywhere else. Finding hourly/weekly basis data! It is almost impossible.